# Retreive Arraylist modified from Adaptater RecyclerView to first activity

Tags: java, android

I've an activity in which I use a RecyclerView. In the Adaptater I modify the content of an ArrayList. How can I retrieve my modified ArrayList in my first activity
Thank you very much for your help
Best regards
Georges

```
holder.imageClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (laPlateaux.get(position).Cat.equals("U7")) {
                keyPlateau = "PlatU7" + "-" + zdte + "-" + laPlateaux.get(position).AccueilNum;}
            else {
                keyPlateau = "PlatU9" + "-" + zdte + "-" + laPlateaux.get(position).AccueilNum; }
            if (laPlateaux.get(position).Cat.equals("U7")) {
                 if (laPlateaux.get(position).Select.equals("N")){
                    mDatabase.child("PlateauxU7").child(keyPlateau).child("Selected").setValue("Y");
                    holder.imageClick.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.valoknew));
                    laPlateaux.get(position).Select = "Y";
                     notifyDataSetChanged();}
                else {
                    mDatabase.child("PlateauxU7").child(keyPlateau).child("Selected").setValue("N");
                    holder.imageClick.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.valnoknew));
                    laPlateaux.get(position).Select = "N";
                     notifyDataSetChanged();}}
            else {
                if (laPlateaux.get(position).Select.equals("N")){
                    mDatabase.child("PlateauxU9").child(keyPlateau).child("Selected").setValue("Y");
                    holder.imageClick.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.valoknew));
                    laPlateaux.get(position).Select = "Y";
                    notifyDataSetChanged();}
                else {
                    mDatabase.child("PlateauxU9").child(keyPlateau).child("Selected").setValue("N");
                    holder.imageClick.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.valnoknew));
                    laPlateaux.get(position).Select = "N";
                    notifyDataSetChanged();}}} }); }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return laPlateaux.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must just implement the public getter in your adapter, that's all.

In the Adapter

```
public List<PlaceholderItem> getKeyPlateau() {
    return keyPlateau;
}
```

In the activity

```
ArrayList<String> keyPlateau = adapter.getKeyPlateau();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to set it up by doing in the adapter :

Comment: public List<ListePlateaux> getlaPlateaux() {
        return laPlateaux;
    }

Comment: Then in my activity :

Comment: ArrayList<ListePlateaux> laPlateaux = (ArrayList<ListePlateaux>) adapterPlateaux.getlaPlateaux();

Comment: But I’m not recovering my ArrayList laPlateaux. I probably didn’t understand everything

Comment: I found my mistake, now it works properly. Thanks